# Not able to append data to the FormData

Tags: angularjs, typescript, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload a file to the server as **multipart /form-data**. For that, I have created the object of a **FormData** and append the files and it's name to it. Unfortunately, the append is not happening and showing nothing as an error. Please help me to resolve this. Following are the codes I've tried.

**HTML**

```
  <input style="font-size:15px;" name="file" type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" placeholder="Upload a file..."/>

      <button [disabled]="!this.fileCollection.length>0" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-s" (click)="uploadFile()" style="position:relative; top: 12px;"> 
          Upload
      </button>
```

**component.ts**

```
fileChangeEvent(fileInput: any): void {
    this.filesToUpload = fileInput.target.files;
    this.uppendFileCollections(this.filesToUpload);
  }

  uppendFileCollections(files): void {
    for (var index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {
      {
        this.fileCollection.push(<TemplateForm>
          {
            fileData: files[index],
            fileName: files[index].name
          }
        );
      }
    }

    this.fileUploaderTitle = this.fileCollection.length + ' file(s) selected.';
  }

  uploadFile() {
    let file: File = this.fileCollection[0]['fileData'];//passing only one file now.

    this.homeService.saveFile(file)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.message == 'success') {
          this.filesToUpload = [];
          this.fileCollection = [];
          this.fileUploaderTitle = 'Choose Files';
          this.showSnackBar();
          this.isLoading = false;
        }
        else {
          console.log('Error on upload:' + response.error);
        }
        this.router.navigate(['/result'])
      })
  }
```

**Service.ts**

```
saveFile(file: File): Promise<any> {
        let uri = `${this.serverApi}/fileUpload`;
        let playload: FormData = new FormData();
        playload.append('file', file,file.name);
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.post(uri, playload, options)
          .toPromise()
          .then((res) => {
            let temp = res.json();
            return { 'statusCode': 200, 'message': 'success', 'result': temp, 'error': {} };
          }
          )
          .catch((error) => {
            return { 'statusCode': 200, 'message': 'failed', 'result': {}, 'error': error };
          }
          )
      }
```

Comment: check your service by debugging it, and see if you have received the object in that name

Comment: @WiselyDCruizer From here itself the append is not working I think. From the server side, it receiving the form data object have no data.

Comment: post your html code and component code

Comment: @WiselyDCruizer I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple format :

```
saveFile(data)
{
 let uri = `${this.serverApi}/fileUpload`;
 const formData: FormData = new FormData();
 formData.append('file',file,file.name);
 return this.http
  .post(uri, formData)
  .map(() => { return true; })
}
```